# Can I have some help optimizing this script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

I wrote a infinite terrain script which works! Saddly everytime the player moves a chunk it lags for a moment. I know my code isn't great but I'm here to learn why :D

I'm unsure of what else to do. I've looked online and found no simple or understandable solution to me because I just don't know enough so I tried to write it on my own and it works but barley.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GEN_InfiniteTerrain : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject targetObject;
    public GameObject chunkObject;
    public int chunkSize;
    public float unitSize;

    public int renderDistance;
    Dictionary<Vector2, GameObject> gridOfChunks = new Dictionary<Vector2, GameObject>();
    List<Vector2> expectedChunkGridPositions = new List<Vector2>();

    public float noiseScale;

    // Infinite terrain values
    float absoluteChunkSize;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Calculate absolute chunk size
        GetAbsoluteChunkSize();

        // Generate base world
        GenerateBase();
    }

    Vector2 lastTargetGridPosition = Vector2.zero;
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        // Get the targets position in world space
        Vector3 targetAbsolutePosition = targetObject.transform.position;

        // Convert the targets world position to grid position (/ 10 * 10 is just rounding to 10)
        Vector2 targetGridPosition = new Vector2();
        targetGridPosition.x = Mathf.RoundToInt(targetAbsolutePosition.x / 10) * 10 / absoluteChunkSize;
        targetGridPosition.y = Mathf.RoundToInt(targetAbsolutePosition.z / 10) * 10 / absoluteChunkSize;

        if (targetGridPosition - lastTargetGridPosition != Vector2.zero)
        {
            GenerateExpectedChunkAreas(targetGridPosition);
            UpdateChunkPositions(targetGridPosition);
        }

        lastTargetGridPosition = targetGridPosition;
    }

    void GenerateBase()
    {
        for (int x = -renderDistance / 2; x < renderDistance / 2; x++)
        {
            for (int z = -renderDistance / 2; z < renderDistance / 2; z++)
            {
                Vector2 gridPosition = new Vector2(x, z);
                Vector3 worldPosition = new Vector3(x * (unitSize * chunkSize), 0, z * (unitSize * chunkSize));
                GameObject chunk = Instantiate(chunkObject, worldPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                chunk.GetComponent<GEN_Chunk>().gridPosition = gridPosition;
                gridOfChunks.Add(gridPosition, chunk);
            }
        }
        GenerateExpectedChunkAreas(Vector2.zero);
    }

    void GenerateExpectedChunkAreas(Vector2 targetGridPosition)
    {
        expectedChunkGridPositions.Clear();
        for (int x = -renderDistance / 2; x < renderDistance / 2; x++)
        {
            for (int z = -renderDistance / 2; z < renderDistance / 2; z++)
            {
                Vector2 gridPosition = new Vector2(x, z) + targetGridPosition;
                expectedChunkGridPositions.Add(gridPosition);
            }
        }
    }

    void UpdateChunkPositions(Vector2 targetGridPosition)
    {
        List<Vector2> positionsWithoutChunks = new List<Vector2>();
        List<Vector2> positionsWithOldChunks = new List<Vector2>();

        for (int chunkCount = 0, x = -renderDistance / 2; x < renderDistance / 2; x++)
        {
            for (int z = -renderDistance / 2; z < renderDistance / 2; z++)
            {
                Vector2 gridPosition = new Vector2(x, z) + targetGridPosition;

                if(!gridOfChunks.ContainsKey(gridPosition))
                {
                    positionsWithoutChunks.Add(gridPosition);
                }
                chunkCount++;
            }
        }

        foreach (GameObject chunk in gridOfChunks.Values)
        {
            if(!expectedChunkGridPositions.Contains(chunk.GetComponent<GEN_Chunk>().gridPosition))
            {
                positionsWithOldChunks.Add(chunk.GetComponent<GEN_Chunk>().gridPosition);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < positionsWithOldChunks.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 worldPosition = new Vector3(positionsWithoutChunks[i].x * absoluteChunkSize, 0, positionsWithoutChunks[i].y * absoluteChunkSize);
            gridOfChunks[positionsWithOldChunks[i]].transform.position = worldPosition;

            // Recalculating noise for chunk based on its new position does lag more but even WITHOUT this it still stutters when player moves around. ( plan to learn threading just to calculate noise on seperate threads )
           // gridOfChunks[positionsWithOldChunks[i]].GetComponent<GEN_Chunk>().ApplyNoise();
        }
    }

    void GetAbsoluteChunkSize()
    {
        absoluteChunkSize = unitSize * chunkSize;
    }
}
```

I need some smooth working infinite terrain (in quotes 'infinite')
And I'd like to learn too!

Comment: If you have working code that you want help improving or optimizing, you should be asking your question on [codereview.se] - that's exactly why the site was created. This site is for programming problems with non-working code or use of a programming tool.

Comment: avoid using "contains".

Comment: avoid "division", reuse variables instead of accessing an array element many times via index.